# github page doesn't exist (the simple jekyll configuration)

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have the simplest (default jekyll) page on github

```
https://github.com/pejot/pejot.github.io
```

When I run locally

```
bundle exec jekyll serve
```

it works fine.

but on the github domain

```
pejot.github.io
```

it says: "There isn't a GitHub Page here."

what can be a problem that it works locally but not on github? Please take into account that page is basically empty. Is the default one generated by jekyll.

Comment: How long has it been? GitHub pages usually take a few minutes to propagate.

Comment: you can see commits history, it's already much more then 10 minutes which it may take up to.

Comment: It seems to work now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I get it!

github takes gh-pages branch for project page and master for the user one.